# CORS: Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true

Tags: ajax, django, node.js, cors, django-cors-headers

I have a setup involving

Frontend server (Node.js, domain: localhost:3000) <---> Backend (Django, Ajax, domain: localhost:8000)

Browser <-- webapp <-- Node.js (Serve the app)

Browser (webapp) --> Ajax --> Django(Serve ajax POST requests)

Now, my problem here is with CORS setup which the webapp uses to make Ajax calls to the backend server. In chrome, I keep getting

> Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true.

doesn't work on firefox either.

My Node.js setup is:

```
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8000/');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
};
```

And in Django I'm using [this middleware](https://gist.github.com/strogonoff/1369619) [along with this](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers)

The webapp makes requests as such:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/blah',
    data: {},
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: successHandler
});
```

So, the request headers that the webapp sends looks like:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE'
Content-Type: application/json 
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: csrftoken=***; sessionid="***"
```

And here's the response header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,*
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE
Content-Type: application/json
```

Where am I going wrong?!

Edit 1: I've been using `chrome --disable-web-security`, but now want things to actually work.

Edit 2: Answer:

So, solution for me `django-cors-headers` config:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://localhost:3000' # Here was the problem indeed and it has to be http://localhost:3000, not http://localhost:3000/
)
```

Comment: For me it is localhost:3000 without http, like this:

    CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
        'localhost:3000',
    )

Comment: Do you mean you use develop the  frontend and backend in one PC?

Comment: how about the frontend and backend in different PC?

Comment: @ixaxaar why you say with the http works for you? we all only ` 'localhost:3000'` works.

Comment: @244boy yeah the point is not the `http`, it is the `/` at the end. I suppose omitting http could work, but I've not really worked on this stuff for some years, so don't really know what works now!

Comment: omitting `http://` just throws: `ERRORS:
?: (corsheaders.E013) Origin 'localhost:3000' in CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST is missing scheme or netloc` in Django 2.2

Comment: Spent hours debugging this - and this thread was the fix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35713682/socket-io-gives-cors-error-even-if-i-allowed-cors-it-on-server

Answer (score 369, accepted):

This is a part of security, you cannot do that. If you want to allow credentials then your `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` must not use `*`. You will have to specify the exact protocol + domain + port. For reference see these questions :

1. [Access-Control-Allow-Origin wildcard subdomains, ports and protocols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003332/access-control-allow-origin-wildcard-subdomains-ports-and-protocols)
2. [Cross Origin Resource Sharing with Credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074665/cross-origin-resource-sharing-with-credentials)

Besides `*` is too permissive and would defeat use of credentials. So set `http://localhost:3000` or `http://localhost:8000` as the allow origin header.

Comment: But what if there's more than one domain?

Comment: @aroth You can give a list of domains. Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains

Comment: What if I'm getting the same error message but there is no `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` in the response?

Comment: @user568109 Could you explain "Besides `*` is too permissive and would defeat use of credentials."?

Comment: What is the "exact domain" if the request comes from mobile device, like it can happen with Cordova?

Comment: Ok, so how exactly does the server know whether or not it should send "*"?

Comment: Is it possible to provide localhost of a different computer than the server? I got this error: "The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:3000/' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: @HugoWood, a man in the middle attack would cause one to send credentials to any (*) server

Comment: @Christian kinda old, but if anyone still curious, this problem happens only for applications running on browsers, because this error is thrown by the browser for security reasons. Other clients such as a mobile app, postman or any other backend code using http client to make a request won't have this problem, so you don't have to worry about the origin and the **exact domain**.

Comment: For more than one domain use it like this     response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));

Comment: @Alisson Reinaldo Silva Sorry, I don't get it. If my backend (which previously allows wildcard) has to allow exact domains of frontend sites now, so that my frontend sites (which wants to send a few requests with credentials to backend) can work. My mobile apps which directly call backend obviously do not have exact domain names, how can they work in the ruleset?

Comment: @LamLe there is nothing in your backend that would block requests from your mobile apps, the backend doesn't block anything here. You only need to whitelist the domain from your frontend web app, because otherwise the **browser** would block the requests from the frontend web app. So it's like the browser is asking the backend *"hey, is it ok if I send you this request from this domain?"* and the backend can reply with *"yes, whatever"* or *"nope, I don't recognize this domain"*, but the **browser blocks** the requests, the backend won't reject the exact same request coming from other clients.

Comment: @LamLe so CORS is a security mechanism adopted by browsers, they are the ones blocking requests if the backend doesn't reply with proper rulesets. Other clients may decide to apply CORS too and block requests, one such example is Unity. You can create mobile games with Unity, they are transpiled into native code for Android/iOS and other platforms, and if your app needs to send requests to a backend, Unity requires a similar CORS validation (may not be exactly CORS, but it's the same idea).

Comment: @ShivamYadav That's the worst thing that you can do in this situation and it completely bypasses the security that CORS is intended to provide. If you reflect the origin of the request and allow credentials the requests to your application would be allowed from any domain which would leave the application vulnerable to CSRF.

Comment: @AlissonReinaldoSilva What should I do if the client requests do come from browsers?

Comment: @Squarish it depends on what are you trying to achieve. If you want to use credentials, you can't use wildcard * for the origin, as per the accepted answer. Why do you need to use credentials true?

Comment: @AlissonReinaldoSilva My goal is to design a public API for which it would be possible for users to create their own frontends. I'm currently using a cookie oauth scheme and trying to pass the authorization cookie through CORS to the user on a successful login.

Comment: @Squarish then if you need credentials: true, you cannot use wildcard * for the origin in the cors response. So either you need to 1) keep a list of your users' origins (you could have an input where they provide their domain for you) and return their domains in the CORS origin response, OR 2) use the request's origin header as the origin for the cors response (which has the same effect as using *) but this kinda defeats the purpose of using cookie through cors, OR 3) use another auth mechanism instead of cookies.

Answer (score 97):

If you are using CORS middleware and you want to send `withCredential` boolean true, you can configure CORS like this:

```
var cors = require('cors');    
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:3000'}));
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks @hamid

Answer (score 66):

Expanding on @Renaud idea, cors now provides a very easy way of doing this:

From cors official documentation found [here](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html):

"
*origin: Configures the Access-Control-Allow-Origin CORS header.
Possible values:
Boolean - set origin to true to reflect the request origin, as defined by req.header('Origin'), or set it to false to disable CORS.*
"

Hence we simply do the following:

```
const app = express();
const corsConfig = {
    credentials: true,
    origin: true,
};
app.use(cors(corsConfig));
```

Lastly I think it is worth mentioning that there are use cases where we would want to allow cross origin requests from anyone; for example, when building a public REST API.

Comment: I like this answer! especially about the fact that there are use cases where you want to allow all origins (many answers here seem to assume that it is always a bad practice).

Answer (score 21):

try it:

```
const cors = require('cors')

const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
    credentials: true,

}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Answer (score 18):

If you are using `express` you can use the [cors](https://github.com/troygoode/node-cors/) package to allow CORS like so instead of writing your middleware;

```
var express = require('express')
, cors = require('cors')
, app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.get(function(req,res){ 
  res.send('hello');
});
```

Comment: Ah, now that's more convenient, however, the result's the same :(  BTW, I'm using `app.use(cors({credentials: true}));`

Comment: You might want to look into [this](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers) Django CORS middleware that is tested.

Comment: So you have two Django middlewares ? I would only use `django-cors-header` app. Make sure you add _localhost_ to `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` setting and set `CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS` to `True`

Comment: Yeah man, tried that before to no avail, had `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True`, `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
        'localhost'
)` and `CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True`  I get these headers: `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000/
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE
Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: BTW, I was using django-cors-headers, but things were not working, so I coupled it with a custom middleware as well.

Comment: After reading this documentation: https://github.com/expressjs/corsuse 

i using this config:

app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:3001'}));

is working for me.

Comment: @allel - that url is no more in use - find the following working url `https://github.com/expressjs/cors`

Answer (score 14):

If you want to allow all origins and keep credentials true, this worked for me:

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: function(origin, callback){
    return callback(null, true);
  },
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
  credentials: true
}));
```

Comment: @TSlegaitis Haha yeah that's why it works for all origins but keeps credentials.  I wouldn't recommend it for security but it does work.

Comment: This worked for me while keeping credentials true, in my case origin was null so nothing else worked except this.

Comment: This is terribly insecure: it exposes users to cross-origin attacks. See https://portswigger.net/research/exploiting-cors-misconfigurations-for-bitcoins-and-bounties

Answer (score 9):

This works for me in development but I can't advise that in production, it's just a different way of getting the job done that hasn't been mentioned yet but probably not the best. Anyway here goes:

You can get the origin from the request, then use that in the response header. Here's how it looks in express:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.header('origin') );
  next();
});
```

I don't know what that would look like with your python setup but that should be easy to translate.

Comment: [Mozilla Dev Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin) expand on the idea of changing the allowed origin to the one from the request. It is suggested to add a 'Vary: Origin' HTTP response header and whitelist allowed domains.

Comment: Whats wrong with this solution in production?

Comment: @Avishay28 this allows all origins so it wouldn't be considered safe

Comment: Yeah of course.. Was talking about situations where you want your server to be open to all websites

Comment: @Renaud `origin` is null. do you mean `host`? Calling `request.headers["host"]` returns `localhost:3000` but doesn't include the protocol, `http://`

Answer (score 4):

(Edit) The previously recomended add-on is not available any longer, you may try [this other one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf)

---

For development purposes in Chrome, installing
[this add on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) will get rid of that specific error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.1.42:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1546163388687' 
from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' 
when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests 
initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

After installing, make sure you add your url pattern to the `Intercepted URLs` by clicking on the AddOn's (*CORS*, green or red) icon and filling the appropriate textbox. An example URL pattern to add here that will work with `http://localhost:8080` would be: `*://*`

Comment: I got it just after installing it, any ideas?

Comment: It worked for me. Warning if you have other similar add-ons you have to uninstall it before try this one.

Comment: please fix the broken link

Comment: Seems like the original add on was removed, I added a new recommendation as an (Edit) at the top

Answer (score 2):

Though we have many solutions regarding the cors origin, I think I may add some missing part. Generally using cors middlware in **node.js** serves maximum purpose like different http methods (get, post, put, delete).

But there are use cases like sending cookie response, we need to enable credentials as true inside the cors middleware Or we can't set **cookie**. Also there are use cases to give access to **all the origin**. in that case, we should use,

```
{credentials: true, origin: true}
```

For specific origin, we need to specify the origin name,

```
{credential: true, origin: "http://localhost:3000"}
```

For multiple origins,

```
{credential: true, origin: ["http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:3001" ]}
```

In some cases we may need multiple origin to be allowed. One use case is allowing developers only. To have this dynamic whitelisting, we may use this kind of function

```
const whitelist = ['http://developer1.com', 'http://developer2.com']
const corsOptions = {
origin: (origin, callback) => {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error())
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `{credentials: true, origin: true}` is insecure. See https://portswigger.net/research/exploiting-cors-misconfigurations-for-bitcoins-and-bounties

Answer (score 1):

CORS ERROR With NETLIFY and HEROKU

Actually, if none of the above solutions worked for you then you might wanna try this.
In my case, the backend was running on Heroku and the frontend was hosted on netlify.
in the .env file, of the frontend, the server_url was written as

```
REACT_APP_server_url = "https://ci-cd-backend.herokuapp.com"
```

and in the backend, all my api calls where written as,

```
app.get('/login', (req, res, err) => {});
```

So, Only change you need to do is, add /api at the end of the routes,

so, frontend base url will look like,

```
REACT_APP_server_url = "https://ci-cd-backend.herokuapp.com/api"
```

and backend apis should be written as,

```
app.get('/api/login', (req, res, err) => {})
```

This worked in my case, and I believe this problem is specifically related when the front end is hosted on netlify.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem with angular, using an auth interceptor to edit the header, before the request gets executed. We used an api-token for authentification, so i had credentials enabled. now, it seems it is not neccessary/allowed anymore

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    req = req.clone({
      //withCredentials: true, //not needed anymore
      setHeaders: {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        'API-TOKEN' : 'xxx'
      },
    });
    
    return next.handle(req);
  }
```

Besides that, there is no side effects right now.

Answer (score 0):

set     'supports_credentials' => true, at config/cors.php
it works like a charm

Comment: The question uses Node.js. This is not useful at all.