# FineUploader Exception : XhrReadyState=0 and XhrResponseStatus=0

Tags: amazon-s3, fine-uploader

We're experiencing FineUploader exceptions with `XhrReadyState=0` and `XhrResponseStatus=0` on 5.4.1 in our production environment intermittently across browsers. We've checked out our CORS configuration for our S3 bucket and we do have the wild card origin header set.

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Was looking at [FineUploader CORS selectively working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337918/fineuploader-cors-selectively-working),  and we do not set the `sendCredentials` value in our configuration.

Error from fine uploader is

> XHR returned response code 0

The XHR response object contains the following values,

- XhrReadyState=0
- XhrResponseText=*empty*
- XhrResponseType=*empty*
- XhrResponseStatus=0
- XhrTimeout=0
- XhrAllResponseHeaders=*empty*

#### Update 1

So we captured a repro of this.  It looks like one of our `OPTIONS` requests is getting a 403 randomly in the middle of the upload.

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) (a7db116d-26ec-4b45-9566-8697d42a7b4c.VOB, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin http://www.ourdomain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (a7db116d-26ec-4b45-9566-8697d42a7b4c.VOB, line 0)
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ourbucket.s3.amazonaws.com/.... 
Origin http://www.ourdomain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Here is the screen grab from the Safari console.  I was suspecting a network problem,  but I wouldn't expect such a quick 403 response if a network issue was .  Also,  previous `OPTIONS` requests had just succeeded before and after the one that 403'd.  We have configured CORS on our S3 bucket.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Status 0 indicates some issue either with your server or with the network. More specifically, it indicates that the response received was completely empty. This can be caused by CORS issues or even a temporary network issue. You'll want to examine these possibilities further in order to determine what is causing the issue for you.

Comment: Ray,  it looks like it might be a CORS issue,  but it's really sporadic.  I've added an update with more details that I'd like to get your thoughts on.

Comment: The fact that the OPTIONS/preflight is failing with a 403 indicates that it is, without a doubt, a CORS issue. Perhaps a temporary issue with AWS. Hard to say for sure.