# .NET webapi endpoint working in Postman but Chrome gives net::ERR_FAILED

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core, .net-core, axios

I have a problem fetching data using React with TypeScript from a webapi (.Net Core 3.0.100).
The webapi project has an endpoint, http://localhost:5000/api/values.
I can browse to this URL directly in Chrome and see the data, I can also access the endpoint succesfully in Postman.

In my root/[React-app]/App.tsx folder I have the following code:

```
  state = {
    values: [],
  };


  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/values').then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      this.setState({
        values: [
          { id: 1, name: 'Value 101' },
          { id: 2, name: 'Value 102' },
        ],
      });
    });
  }
```

When I go to localhost:3000 on my host the console cannot access "values", the status is (failed) and gives the following error: GET http://localhost:5000/api/values net::ERR_FAILED

When I expand the error the first row is showing an error in "dispatchXhrRequest" under xhr.js

There is a red underlining under request.send(requestData)

```
  request.send(requestData);
  });
};
```

I am totally lost, I can access any other endpoint, such as jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
using the same code above, but the not http://localhost:5000/api/values

How can this problem be fixed? I have tried for 2 days and I cannot solve it so need help from the community.

Project details:

React with TypeScript
React v17.0.1
.Net Core 3.0.100
3 class libraries (Application, Domain, Persistence)
1 webapi (API)

I have extensively checked other questions and they seem to either have a response to older versions of React and/or .Net Core or they do not solve this particular problem.

Comment: do you have any ad blocker etc?

Comment: I do, I removed the plugin. Same error message.

Comment: It could be due to many reasons, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22665232/what-can-cause-chrome-to-give-an-neterr-failed-on-cached-content-against-a-ser

Comment: I just tried, for ad blocker etc, the actual error is `net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`, so it is unlikely ad blocker

Comment: Actually, it was the CORS, thank you for showing me in the right direction. I will add the code that solved the problem.

Comment: glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Startup.CS I had to add the following to the ConfigureServices method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)     
services.AddCors(opt => 
                {
                     opt.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", policy => 
                     {
                         policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
                     });
                });
```

And the below added to the Configure method:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
 app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

Thanks to ABOS for linking to a question that had a hint to the solution.