Fetch API and net::ERR_FAILED error in private mode
I use the fetch API to download images and use them later on my page. I use Promise.all to fetch an array of images, around 200 images, in parallel.
This works perfectly fine on desktop browsers, in normal and private mode and also on mobile browsers in both modes except on Chrome Android in private mode? Some of the requests (not all) returns with an net::ERR_FAILED error.
I guess there is some kind of limitations on Chrome Android in private mode (again, this works fine in normal mode) that causes this but I can't find what is it? Is there a limit on the number of parallel requests? Is there a limit on the total size that can be be downloaded?
Could anyone point me out a reference on the subject?
Thanks a lot!

https://stackoverflow.com/q/22665232/1427878 has info on different potential causes, and ways to debug (not sure if the latter is easily achievable on mobile though?)

Thank you but I think that theses causes are not related to my issue. It just seems to me that in incognito mode on Android, Chrome sets a limit on the total data size that can be downloaded through fetch. If I try to fetch less images to stay below 35 MB of data, this problem does not occur. Can anyone confirm this?
