# Access-Control-Allow-Origin is added to the header when request is made from Python(Google Colab), but not when the request is made from ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, cors, azure-api-management, flask-cors

My app is structured as follows: React frontend -> Azure Api Management -> Flask backend.

The Flask app allows all origins.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})
```

The Azure Api Management inbound and outbound policy looks like this:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-backend-service id="apim-generated-policy" backend-id="webapp_test" />
        <cors allow-credentials="true">
            <allowed-origins>
                <origin>https://va-prod-dashboard.azurewebsites.net</origin>
                <origin>http://localhost:9000</origin>
                <origin>http://localhost:3000</origin>
            </allowed-origins>
            <allowed-methods>
                <method>GET</method>
                <method>POST</method>
            </allowed-methods>
        </cors>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

The issue started when I tried to make a POST request from the React frontend. When making the request from python(google colab), I printed the response header and it had **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**: *(all).

The React post request fails with: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

What is strange to me is that **only post requests fail, only in javascript**.

Does anybody have any idea what might be the culprit?

Thank you for taking the time to read this!

Comment: I think you need to add that `<cors>` directive also to `<outbound>` or try what's in that link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-cross-domain-policies#AllowCrossDomainCalls

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe)

Comment: You can refer to [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65644658/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-fl), [React component has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403651/react-component-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-no-access-control-allow-origin) and ['Access-Control-Allow-Origin' issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41497674/access-control-allow-origin-issue-when-api-call-made-from-react-isomorphic-ap)

Comment: CORS are sent by the server, not by the client, pretty sure it's to do with the MS rproxy

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to Daniel W, for your valuable suggestion. Posting as an answer to help other community members.

> You need to add `<cors>` directive also to `<outbound>`.

> CORS are sent by the server, not by the client, pretty sure it's to do with the MS Proxy.

> Please refer this [Microsoft-Doc-CORS-APIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-cross-domain-policies#AllowCrossDomainCalls) for more information.