# Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie" Error in send requests Flask to another severs with Ajax

Tags: flask, cross-browser

I have a flask app and I want to send a request with Ajax from my page to another website on the internet( http://hihihi.com/v1/user_likes...for example and this App not flask and I can't change or add any code in the hihihi App).
I set a cookie in my Ajax requests but blocked by the browser. how can I fix this?

Back end flask:

```
@app.route('/tr')
def test():
    return render_template('tr.html')
```

And in tr.html file as shown as I set header Ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://hihihi.com/api',
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json',headers:{'Cookie' :  'sdfsdfsdfsfdszfvgzzf'}
                    datatype: 'json',
                   
                })
                .done(function(data) {
.
.
.
```

Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie" Error:
[image: Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"]

In addition, I use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26395623) but not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are making a same origin request all you need to do is set document.cookie before you make the request.

Comment: How can I do this? i set like `document.cookie = "username=John Doe";` but not work and It has the same problem as before

Comment: There is no way to change the cookies for a different origin from the current origin