# How to enable CORS in Python Dash

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

I've seen that you can enable CORS for Flask ([How to enable CORS in flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594893/how-to-enable-cors-in-flask)), but I have a Dash app and I want to enable something like

headers = {
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
}

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable CORS on Dash by using flask_cors

Here a snippet you could try:

```
import dash
from flask_cors import CORS

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
server = app.server
CORS(server)

@app.route("/")
def helloWorld():
  return "Hello, cross-origin-world!"
```

At this link https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ you can find the documentation for the Flask-CORS library with instructions regarding how to install and configure it