# Running Flask-Vue site with Gunicorn and Nginx

Tags: vue.js, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I have website that was created by a colleague that I’ve taken over. It’s been designed with Flask and Vue. I’ve been able to run this locally after some troubleshooting, but when trying to deploy this onto a server, I can’t get the site running.

I’ve followed numerous tutorials where I’ve used the following:

**Gunicorn:**
`gunicorn --workers 1 --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 -m 777 wsgi:app`

**Config for nginx:**

```
    server { 
        listen 80; 
        server_name 192.168.1.1;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

        # To allow POST on static pages
        error_page  405     =200 $uri;

        location / {
            root frontend/dist;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /config {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000;
        }
    }
```

Within my frontend `App.vue`, I link to the backend - which I've tried:

```
backend_url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000'
backend_url: 'http://192.168.1.1:5000'
```

Then when I load up 192.168.1.1, the frontend starts initially, but when it comes to communicating with the backend via different flask @app.routes, it stops.

I’ve also tried using a socket to connect between gunicorn and nginx, but I get the same issue.

When looking on the console in Chrome, I get:

`POST http://192.168.1.1:5000/config net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT 192.168.1.1/:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received`

Whereas in Firefox, I get:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://192.168.1.1:5000/config. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null)`

This is why I added `add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;` within my nginx config file

Any ideas?

**CORS:**

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to enable CORS in flask for the domain and/or IP serving the Vue app.

See flask-cors extension [How to enable CORS in flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594893/how-to-enable-cors-in-flask)

Comment: Thanks, but I believe I already have this code - added above