# API error (CORS) between Flask App and React frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, flask, cors

I have built a Flask App website and hosted it on Heroku. Now I'm trying to use React in order to build a more `erm` reactive front-end. I added API route in the Flask app that returns a JSON with some information.

```
@app.route("/api/", methods=["GET"])
def get_country_info():
    *some procesing*
    return jsonify(data)
```

When I test this with Postman I get the expected JSON, but when I try to fetch the data with react (local development server) I get:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://values-chart-generator.herokuapp.com/api?social_value=religion_score&demo_group=education&country=germany. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 308.

I don't understand where the problem is, react or flask, or how to fix the issue. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a flask developer so I can't give you code to fix it.

but your problem is due to same origin policy which is a **browser** security mechanism that prevents communication between different origins.
that's why it works with postman and not with react

so your solution would be to add cors configurations to your flask app to allow frontend origin accessing your backend.

flask code could be found here [How to enable CORS in flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594893/how-to-enable-cors-in-flask)

more about cors [here](https://sentry.io/answers/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-error-while-postman-does-not/#:%7E:text=Postman%20does%20not%20enforce%20CORS,from%20accessing%20cross%2Dorigin%20resources.)

Comment: Yes, you are right. That seems to be the problem. Will update heroku app and test again. Will let you know if it works. Thank you for being my friend on my learning journey! :)

Comment: Yes, Flask CORS solved the issue. Will have to fiddle around to make CORS access more restrictive.