# POST Err_Connection_Refused

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask, backend

I just want to transfer data from my javascript file to python. I tried to do this via ajax request, but I get a console error:

> POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

here is a part of my code responsible for transferring data from js:

```js
function getAccountInfo () {
      
      const number = 5
      const message = 'some text'

      const dict_values = {number, message}
      const s = JSON.stringify(dict_values);
      console.log(s)
      $.ajax({
        url:"http://127.0.0.1:5000/test",
        type:"POST",
        contentType:"application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(s)
      }); 
    }
```

that is my python code:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, session
import json

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    output = request.get_json()
    print(output)
    print(type(output))
    result = json.loads(output)
    print(result)
    print(type(result))

    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

the flask application by default is launched on `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` :
[image]

so i cant imagine why i have this problem

Comment: Where, exactly, is this code running?  On your local computer?  In a docker container?

Comment: Your JavaScript code is executing on a different domain or port than your Flask server?

Comment: It seems to me that you are sending the data to the wrong url. I think you wanted to reach `http://127.0.0.1:5000/test`.

Comment: yes, by default my react app is building on http://localhost:3000

Comment: on my local computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your JavaScript code is executing on a different domain or port than your Flask server, **you might encounter CORS issues**.

You need to set up CORS properly, you can use the `flask-cors` package to handle CORS, this way:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, session
from flask_cors import CORS
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
```

Check this out:

- [Understanding CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845203/understanding-cors)
- [How to enable CORS in flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594893/how-to-enable-cors-in-flask)

Comment: this helped and I don't get any more errors, but for some reason python still doesn't get my variables.

Comment: @why You mean that it doesn't recognize the payload?

Comment: yes, it does not output any messages that it should output when receiving a request

Comment: Did you debug to see if the problem is with the values or the `print()`?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but I didn't get any notification from the debugger

Comment: lets talk about it in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254870/post-err-connection-refused)

Comment: due to the fact that I'm new to stackoverflow, I don't have enough reputation to talk in messages. I have debugged again and now every time I call getAccountInfo() I receive this message: `127.0.0.1 - - [10/Aug/2023 21:17:05] " [ 33mOPTIONS /test HTTP/1.1 [0m" 404 -` on my python shell

Comment: In my tests it works... is there any way we can communicate directly? So as not to fill the answer with out-of-scope comments.

Comment: I can show you my code on dicrord stream so you can find the error easier i guess(discord: whycringe)

Comment: solicitation sended!