# CORS issue is preventing me from sending POST queries to backend in spite of mitigation

Tags: python, azure, cors, azure-web-app-service

When trying to connect azure hosted web app for front end with azure hosted web app for backend, I recieve cors issue in spite of attempted mitigation.

Access to fetch at 'https://..../api/answer' from origin 'https://....azurewebsites.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I have attempted the following:

1. Checked the api endpoint and URL's - make sure they are correct
2. Changed backend from listening on port 5000 (http) for POST to HTTPS port mitigating mixed content errors.
3. made available on all networks 0.0.0.0
4. specified (*) for CORS on backend webapp in azure, to allow all.
5. used flask_cors library to specify the front end domain should be allowed.

I expected this to mitigate the CORS issue as flask_cors directs the backend to permit the specified domain from the actual code inside, and using the wildcard (*) sytmbol in azure\webapp\api\cors to allow all.

Still recieving the cors error above, have no clue how to fix. URL's and API's are all correct, code is functional, just blocking the POST.

Please let me know if I can improve my question or if there is any information that I should have provided.

Comment: Could you confirm if you see successful `OPTIONS` requests in the developer console?

Answer (score 0):

> Access to fetch at 'https://..../api/answer' from origin 'https://....azurewebsites.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

To resolve this error, you need to allow origins in the Azure App Service.

As you have deployed frontend and backend code in two different App Services, you need to allow origins in both the apps.

- You have to allow access to all origins or particular origin:
- If you are enabling `Enable Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`, you need to specify the origin by adding domains of each web app.

[image]

- If you are not enabling `Enable Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`, you can provide access to all the origins by mentioning **`*`** in both the app services.

[image]

(or)

You can enable CORS for all routes with **flask_cors** extension and wrap your `app`  with  `CORS(app)`.

Thanks @[Billal Begueradj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53997253/19991670) for the code.

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
```

> 1. used flask_cors library to specify the front end domain should be allowed. Still recieving the cors error above, have no clue how to fix.

If there is any error in your route, it will still lead to CORS error related message which has nothing to do with the CORS.