# How to resolve CORS issue when making AJAX requests to a Flask server from a frontend?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, server

I'm developing a web application using Flask for the backend and JavaScript for the frontend. However, I am facing issues with CORS policy when trying to make AJAX requests from my frontend to the Flask server.

Here is a exemple of my JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#escolherimagem").click(function() {
        $("#fileInput").click();
    });`

    $("#fileInput").change(function() {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('image', $(this)[0].files[0]);
        
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://12*.0.*.1:5***/detect',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                if (response.is_healthy) {
                    alert('O animal na imagem é considerado saudável.');
                } else {
                    alert('O animal na imagem "Não" é considerado saudável.');
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.error('Erro ao enviar imagem:', error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And here is the CORS configuration on my Flask server:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
```

How can I resolve this CORS issue and get my AJAX requests accepted by my Flask server?

I have configured CORS on my Flask server using the flask-cors extension, but I am still getting CORS errors in the browser when I try to make a request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable CORS in flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594893/how-to-enable-cors-in-flask)

Comment: Please post the verbatim error messages.

Comment: Are you making the request from HTTPS: protocol to HTTP: protocol (your server)?

Answer (score -1):

_________________********************import this code********************

from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(_name_)
CORS(app, resources={r"/detect": {"origins": "http://yourfrontenddomain.com"}})

if _name_  == '_*main*_':
app.run(debug=True)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

CORS(app, resources={r"/detect": {"origins": "*"}})

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).