# Access-Control-Allow-Origin angularjs to php

Tags: php, angularjs, http, cors, lighttpd

my scenario is composed by two webserver one local and one remote.

Local webserver (Apache) process a web app in which I want make an ajax request to remote webserver (Lighttpd).

Ajax request use angularjs $http.

```
var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://url/myphp.php',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('username:password'),
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    xhrFields: {
       withCredentials: true
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    data: xmlString
}

$http(req).then(function () {
    console.log("OK!");
});
```

Remote php script is:

```
<?php
    echo "You have CORS!";
?>
```

Unfortunately I got a

```
401 Unhauthorized
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://url/myphp.php. Response to    preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8888' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

Remote web server has .htpasswd authentication mode enable and CORS request configured.

Follow a piece of lighttpd.conf

```
setenv.add-response-header = ( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" => "*" )
```

Comment: What browser are you using @gravi?

Comment: Both Chrome and Firefox

Comment: I had this same problem, and apparently, chrome straight up blocks all of these kinds of requests, despite the headers

Answer (score 4):

For add-response-header to work in lighttpd you must enable mod_setenv in your server.modules. However, you have to enable this mod_setenv before mod_status.

```
server.modules = (
    # ...
    "mod_fastcgi",
    "mod_rewrite",
    "mod_redirect",
    "mod_setenv", ## before mod_status
    "mod_status",
    # ...
)
```

Alternatively you could use PHP to output the cors header

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
?>
```

I also want to add that if you are sending http basic/digest auth data you cannot use wildcards for the origin. You have to use the actual source domain

```
setenv.add-response-header = ( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" => "example.com" )
setenv.add-response-header = ( "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" => "true" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are doing a cross domain POST, Angular is making a pre-flight OPTIONS request to check the Access Origin headers before making the POST.
The NET tab in your browser will confirm this.
Your server isn't responding well to the OPTIONS request and therefore Angular refuses to make the POST.

If you POST to your server with POSTMAN is everything OK?

I believe it is possible to configure Angular to not make the pre-flight request.

Alternatively, configure your server to respond correctly to OPTIONS requests, in particular returning the correct Access Origin headers in response to the OPTIONS request. (OPTIONS is just trying to find out if your server has these headers set, if it hasn't then why bother making the POST?)

Hopefully this information will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

`*` can not be used in the case of credentials.

Server is disregarding your
`setenv.add-response-header` statement.

See the answer here:

[CORS: Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743396/cors-cannot-use-wildcard-in-access-control-allow-origin-when-credentials-flag-i)