# Mandrill XMLHttpRequest Error - invalid Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers

Tags: javascript, express, heroku, cors, mandrill

I have an app on Heroku at http://random-name.herokuapp.com that sends emails with Mandrill.  However, regardless of whether I'm running the app locally at `localhost:5000` or remotely on Heroku, I throw the following error when trying to send emails:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: A wildcard '*'
>   cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the
>   credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://random-name.herokuapp.com' is
>   therefore not allowed access.

There's a lot of documentation on Stack Overflow about this error (see [CORS: Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743396/cors-cannot-use-wildcard-in-access-control-allow-origin-when-credentials-flag-i)), and consequently, I set my express headers to the following:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:5000 http://random-name.herokuapp.com");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

However, this doesn't seem to solve the issue.  I couldn't find anything useful in Mandrill's documentation either.  I'm guessing I'm specifying the headers incorrectly, or perhaps they aren't even being used.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` takes a single value, not a space separated list.

You need to return whatever the client sends in the `Origin` request header (test to make sure that is an acceptable origin to you first though!).

Comment: So it looks like they response headers are a wildcard:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8`

Comment: What do you mean by "return whatever the client sends"?

Comment: @sir_thursday — You tried using a wildcard and the error message clearly told you that because you set `withCredentials` you aren't allowed to use a wildcard.

Comment: @sir_thursday — The client says `Origin: http://example.com` then you must say `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused.  Are you saying to use a wildcard, because that's what the client is responding with?  I've tried that as well, and it throws the same error.

Comment: @sir_thursday — You must not use a wildcard. The client isn't responding with anything. The client makes requests. The server responds. Your original code was responding with a wildcard. That was wrong. That was why you got the first error message you quoted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101522/discussion-between-sir-thursday-and-quentin).