# Socket IO problem: 'Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'url' from origin 'url' has been blocked by CORS policy.'

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, cors, cpanel

I experience a problem to establish a websocket connection between a proxy server and browser. The idea is to add data to charts per minute by sending requests to the TikTok API. The server code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const nodemon = require('nodemon');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const cors = require('cors');
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(
    cors({
        origin: "https://fluence.noit.eu"
    })
);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('A user connected');

    // Handle the real-time statistic request from the client
    socket.on('sendAccessToken', (accessToken) => {
        fetch('https://open.tiktokapis.com/v2/user/info/?fields=follower_count,likes_count', {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
            }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            // Emit the data back to the client
            socket.emit('realTimeStatisticData', data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // Emit the error back to the client
            socket.emit('realTimeStatisticError', error);
        });
    });

    // You can add more socket event handlers here

    // Example: Send a message to the connected client
    socket.emit('message', 'Welcome to the real-time statistics server');

    // Example: Listen for a client message and broadcast it to all clients
    socket.on('chatMessage', (message) => {
        io.emit('chatMessage', message);
    });

    // Handle disconnect
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('A user disconnected');
    });
});

app.listen()
```

My browser code is:

```
    let accessToken = JSON.parse('<?php echo isset($_COOKIE["tiktok_access_token"]) ? json_encode($_COOKIE["tiktok_access_token"]) : json_encode($accessToken) ?>');

    const socket = io('https://fluence-api.noit.eu');

    socket.on('connect', () => {
        // When the WebSocket connection is established, send the access token to the server
        socket.emit('sendAccessToken', accessToken);
    });

    socket.on('realTimeStatisticData', (data) => {
        // Handle the received data here
        let date = new Date();
        let hours = date.getHours();
        let minutes = date.getMinutes();

        if (minutes < 10) {
            minutes = String(date.getMinutes()).padStart(2, '0');
        }

        let time = hours + ":" + minutes;

        // Extract necessary information from data
        let followers = data.data.user.follower_count;
        let likes = data.data.user.likes_count;

        // Update the charts with the new data
        followersLive.data.labels.push(time);
        followersLive.data.datasets[0].data.push(followers);
        followersLive.update();

        likesLive.data.labels.push(time);
        likesLive.data.datasets[0].data.push(likes);
        likesLive.update();
    });
```

The exact errors are:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKvDE.png)

I tried to add { transports : ['websocket'] } to `const socket = io('https://echo.websocket.events', { transports : ['websocket'] });`.

I also tried to set cors origins in the server side.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Socket.io gives CORS error even if I allowed cors it on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35713682/socket-io-gives-cors-error-even-if-i-allowed-cors-it-on-server)

Answer (score 0):

On the server-side you can add CORS to the socket itself.

```
const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: process.env.WEB_URL,
        methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    },
});
```

Adding CORS to your socket should solve your problem. The environment variable
`process.env.WEB_URL` is basically the URL of your frontend.