# Send cookies in ajax angular

Tags: angularjs

I want to send the document cookie in the http call in angular.
I have already used withCredentials but it can only send the browser level cookie.
I also use the cross domain ,but it is not working fine.
Below is the code which I am using.

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url,
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
    crossDomain: true,    
    header:{ 'SHOPSESSIONID' : sessionStorage.getItem("SHOPSESSIONID") }
}).success(function(data){
    return data;
}).error(function(data){
   return data;
});
```

Comment: what is the error your facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$httpProvider` in config phase:

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
}])
```

and you could give up the `xhrFields` and `crossDomain` proporties

btw, angular uses `then` instead of `success`, and `catch` instead of `error`. (that is the [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) syntax)

Comment: After adding your line it show "A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true"Now using the below code.
(function () {'use strict';angular.module('app').config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;$httpProvider.defaults.crossDomain = true;}]).service('UtilityService', ['$log', '$q', '$http', function ($log, $q, $http) {this.getHTTPGET= function(url){return   $http({method: 'GET',url: url}).then (function(data){return data;}).catch(function(data){return data;});};}]);})();

Comment: you need to change the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in server side, view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743396/cors-cannot-use-wildcard-in-access-control-allow-origin-when-credentials-flag-i