# $_COOKIE not working when php file called using xmlhttprequest

Tags: php, ajax

Hi anyone please help me. I writted on php simple code test.php. I am just reading cookie only and displaying it. when i execute the below url in chrome browser i am get response

```
https://www.domainname.com/cbscheck/test.php
```

response

```
testa3433^| 1^|1^|0da1d48927ec9118d271cc6a4f0df3e90ee4d296^|1
```

same php url i called in below html file using xmlhttprequest but i am not getting the above reponse.

```
file:///G:/Hari/MyTaks/Chat/chatCheck.html
```

response i am getting empty.

My perception `$_COOKIE` not working  when i called using `xmlhttprequest`. please any help me how to resolve it. i shared code below

**testCheck.htm**

```
<html>
<body>
<div id = 'onlineUsers' class='bottomDiv'>
</div>
<script>

  var url = 'https://www.somedomain.com/cbscheck/test.php';
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {       
        document.getElementById("onlineUsers").innerHTML = this.responseText;   
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", url , true);
  xhttp.send();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

test.php

```
<?php
echo $_COOKIE["loginInfo"];
?>
```

Comment: How and when is the cookie set? Are the PHP and the HTML/JS on the same server? Checked the console for errors?

Comment: cookie setting in login

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `xhttp.withCredentials = true;` to send credentials (and COOKIES too) to the target server using `XMLHttpRequest`. For more information look the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials).

The next problem you faced is about `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. Your server sends `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header, and thats why your browser rejects your `XMLHttpRequest`. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header means that your server application allows you to send requests from frontend to ANY other server. With combination of `xhttp.withCredentials = true` it's very big vulnerability, cause malware js script on your page can send user's credentials to any other place. Thats why your browser rejects your request. You should add yours domain to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header and remove `*`. This problem was already solved in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743396/cors-cannot-use-wildcard-in-access-control-allow-origin-when-credentials-flag-i/19744754#19744754) question.

Comment: Failed to load https://www.agarwalmatrimony.com/cbscheck/test.php: i tried i got the following error The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Comment: @hariprasad this is other problem. You can’t return wildcard in this header in case you want to send cookies to the server with XMLHttpRequest. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19744754/3838486

Comment: @hariprasad, does it help? I also updated my answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that domain the cookie is set on and domain you are making ajax request to are the same. Also, check the url path the cookie is set on.

Browser will send cookies only to the domain and within the url path it was set on (if you don't apply specific cross-domain rules).

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to run in server if you open html directly in browser it will not understand php code so that's why it's not working.

Comment: <?php
echo $_COOKIE["loginInfo"].'test';
?>  just i change my code to above i am getting test but not cookie info

Comment: in which page you set cookie?

Comment: i am setting in login page

Comment: that's why if you open file:///G:/Hari/MyTaks/Chat/chatCheck.html this page directly then it is not call login page so it will not set cookie.