# calling Https url on Http get request angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

I have a **Https url** and want to send request to get data from that URL , scenario 1: 
***from my browser*** If I hit the Url i get the response whereas from my Angularjs App  I get always an error 401 , but if I hit the Api from browser I always get the correct response

for security reasons I couldn't use Url here but what I want is to:

```
  $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "https://urlAdresss/",
        headers: {
            "Accept-Language": "en-US, en;q=0.8",
            "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
        },
    }).then(function (_response) {
        console.log(_response
     }
```

I always get unauthorized I am network as well as On console any help will be greatly appreciated ,

but If I hit the same Url from browser I get the response It means the backend is working fine

I think I am missing something in my get request that's why getting the error

Comment: Possible CORS issue? Api and angular are running on different hosts?

Comment: @lzagkaretos api is on server I am trying to hit the api from local host can be the problem?

Comment: It is very likely. Please check your browser console and network tab for more information.

Comment: it awlays says unauthorized but if i enter URl in browser it returns data :-(

Comment: Did you check browser console (F12) for something like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` missing header or related stuff? Running through localhost of course.

Comment: yeah but getting only the same thing i mentioned

Comment: Can you please provide with a specific url? If it is accessible in public of course.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161402/discussion-between-kumail-hussain-and-lzagkaretos).

Comment: @lzagkaretos please see chat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) issue.

In AngularJS side, you should use the following configuration in order for `$http` service to automatically send authorization headers to http requests.

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
    .config(function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    });
```

And in backend you should specify explicitly allowed origins (eg. `http://localhost:8888`).
Also, note some points from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743396/cors-cannot-use-wildcard-in-access-control-allow-origin-when-credentials-flag-i/19744754#19744754).

> If you want to allow credentials then your Access-Control-Allow-Origin must not use *.