# Error when accessing ASP.NET Core WebApi from Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I have some issues with calling my ASP.NET Core WebAPI from my Ionic app.

I can see in the developer tools that the data get’s loaded correctly, but Ionic is giving me an error:

error message from Ionic:
[image]

data loaded from the api:

[image]

CORS is enabled in the api:

```
 public class Startup
 {
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors();   
        services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>(opt =>
            opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("TodoList"));
        services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost"));
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

I think the error is caused by Ionic or Angular. When I’m loading the data from a public api, everything works fine. I’ve also tried accessing the api with ssl and without.

When you have any questions, feel free to ask me in the comments.

**Edit**

This is how I call the api:

```
@Injectable()
export class RestProvider {

apiUrl = 'https://localhost:5001/api';

constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

getTodoItems() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/todo').subscribe(data => {
        resolve(data);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

and this is my controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TodoController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly TodoContext _context;

    public TodoController(TodoContext context)
    {
        _context = context;

        if (_context.TodoItems.Count() == 0)
        {
            _context.TodoItems.Add(new TodoItem { Title = "Item1" });
            _context.TodoItems.Add(new TodoItem { Title = "Item2" }); 
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<List<TodoItem>> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.TodoItems.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I had this problem, i solved that with adding cors allow origin to web.config also, i dont use any proxy   any chrome plugin. All API functions work fine

Comment: And you must adding a nuget library in your asp project and manipulate your route.

Comment: Im not sure this error caused by cros, because you didnt shared you http.post codes to us

Comment: @mohsensolhnia There is no web.config in ASP.NET Core. I've enabled cors in ASP.NET Core like this: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1) . The error is not caused by cors. I'm able to call the api and get the data but Ionic gives me that error.

Comment: maybe your returned json size is big.... cant solve until see your code

Comment: @mohsensolhnia Please see my edit. I've added the controller and the provider which calls the api.

Comment: Well, you are calling GET. So, you can see result of todo in any browser. Copy  paste https  ://  localhost:5001/api/todo to your  browser. But im not sure you got any result in localhost with https protocol.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47855856/calling-https-url-on-http-get-request-angularjs

Comment: @mohsensolhnia fixed it. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Ah ok, Good lock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it by adding the port number:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8100").AllowAnyMethod());
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ionic.config.json file to configure a proxy in your app:

```
{
  "name": "proxy-example",
  "app_id": "",
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api",
      "proxyUrl": "http://cors.api.com/api"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then when doing the http call:

```
httpClient.get(proxyHost + '/api');
```

More info [Ionic Blog](https://blog.ionicframework.com/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/)

Comment: Thank your for the hint. I had to add "rejectUnauthorized": false to the proxy because I'm using a self signed certificate.

Comment: Pleasure! You could even use [mitm proxy](https://mitmproxy.org/), it has a certificate you can install on your phone and use to test API calls on self-signed certificates.

Comment: never use proxy. it dosnt work in native device specially in ios

Comment: You can't say never use proxy. Proxy is mostly for ionic serve -cl which will launch in chrome/firefox/IE. On mobile device the origin is the document itself, not a nodejs server serving the code.