# Recommended way of allowing all origin in golang when withCredential is true?

Tags: http, go, cookies, cors

Sending cookies cross domain requires `withCredential` setting to `true` which means `access-control-allow-origin` cannot be wild card.

But there is an easy way around this.

```
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", r.Header.Get("Origin"))
```

This will effectively allow all origin, but is this the recommended way of doing this?

It seems like there is a reason for not allowing all origins

[CORS: Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743396/cors-cannot-use-wildcard-in-access-control-allow-origin-when-credentials-flag-i)'

What is the general recommended way of allowing all origin when `withCredential` is true?

Comment: You should only allow trusted origins.

Comment: 1) Create a list of allowed origins, 2) check the `r.Header.Get("Origin")` value to see if it’s an allowed origin in the list, 2a) If `r.Header.Get("Origin")` isn’t an allowed origin, do nothing (don’t send the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header back at all, 2b) if `r.Header.Get("Origin")` is an allowed origin in  your list, then do `w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", r.Header.Get("Origin"))`

Comment: Allowing all origins with credentials is wildly insecure, because it exposes your users to cross-origin attacks, as described in https://portswigger.net/research/exploiting-cors-misconfigurations-for-bitcoins-and-bounties. Don't do it. Instead, only allow origins from a restricted allowlist. Or if you must allow all origins, don't rely on cookie-based authentication.