# Configure Axios and Flask to use CORS with cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, flask, cors, axios

Frontend runs at `localhost:3000`
Server runs at `localhost:9000`

I am able to make a CORS requests without access to cookies.

Sample Axios Request

```
axios.post(SERVER+'/createUser', params)
        .then( resp=>{
            //not important
        });
```

(working: able to access resources from other server)

I was unable to save/send the HttpOnly cookie [session implementation] that the server `localhost:9000` sets

Expected Process Flow

Call to `localhost:9000/authenticate`

`localhost:9000/authenticate` returns a response with a HttpOnly cookie

subsequent requests to `localhost:9000` carry this cookie

To try to access this cookie with axios I added the header `withCredentials:true` 
referenced by the [documentation for axios](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config). For clarity:

```
let headers = {
    withCredentials:true
}
export function authenticate(creds){
    return dispatch => {
        axios.post(SERVER+'/authenticate', creds, headers)
            .then( resp => {
                //not important
            });
    };
}
```

After which I received the following error:

> Failed to load http://localhost:9000/authenticate: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the
>   wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin
>   'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The
>   credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is
>   controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

For clarity, the first (OPTIONS) request is sent and after a 'successful' response, the error is thrown. OPTIONS request:
[image: OPTIONS REQUEST RESPONSE INFO]

My server uses `Flask-Cors` library, after reading the [cookie documentation](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#using-cors-with-cookies) and a few other links, this is how the server is setup for CORS

```
... normal app init
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static')
...
cors = CORS(app, origins=["http://localhost:3000"], headers=['Content-Type'], expose_headers=['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'], supports_credentials=True)
...
@app.route('/authenticate', methods=['POST'])
def authenticate():
    ...
```

I only set the method as POST because (1) the [cookie documentation](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#using-cors-with-cookies) also restricted it to POST and (2) the OPTIONS request seemingly goes through (as referenced by the image) and (3) when I do include OPTIONS as a possible method for the route, when the first request is sent it goes into the method and I have no idea what to return so if someone knows what is the correct response when the OPTIONS method is included please do post.

Other Links

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/569

[Why does my JavaScript get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error when Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)

[CORS: Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743396/cors-cannot-use-wildcard-in-access-control-allow-origin-when-credentials-flag-i)

[Set-Cookie header has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288437/set-cookie-header-has-no-effect/46412839#46412839)

Comment: The error message after withCredentials=true is pretty clear. You cannot use wildcard as the value of this header in this case and must set this value dynamically server-side. Otherwise look into Access-Control-Request-Headers and Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

Comment: please correct me if i'm wrong @marekful, however doesn't the origins=["http://localhost:3000"] not achieve this, also wouldn't the response header include 'Vary:Origin' ?

Comment: Try sending `Access-Control-Request-Headers: Cookie, Set-Cookie` with the request and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Cookie, Set-Cookie` with the response.

Answer (score 9):

The code looks like you are defining `withCredentials` as a HTTP header. But that's not exaclty how it works.

`withCredentials` is actually an option which will enable a http header, but it's not a http header in itself.

Try creating the promise like this:

```
const axiosWithCookies = axios.create({
  withCredentials: true
});
const promise = axiosWithCookies.get(url);
```

The resulting http header will actually look as follows.
But you don't have to add this manually. This will be taken care of if you create the axios instance as above.

```
Cookie: JSESSIONID=...
```