# Reactjs to Webapi on ASP.net Core 2.2 fails with error 415 in app but not in Postman

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, fetch, asp.net-core-webapi

It can do a GET OK, but it just can't do a POST. I have tried all manner of Header combinations. Its to the localhost.

Here is my Reactjs App call

```html
export function saveStaff(data) {
       return fetch(baseUrl, {
    mode: "no-cors",
    method: "POST", 
    headers: {
      Host: "localhost:44370",
      Allow: "GET, POST",
      Accept: "application/json, text/plain",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: { Name: "tuesday", Department: "tuesday", visitorcount: 0 } // data // JSON.stringify(data)
  })
    .then(handleResponse)
    .catch(handleError);
}
```

Here are the headers from Postman this works!

```
POST /api/StaffNamesAPI HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:44370
Allow: GET, POST
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json, text/plain
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.16.3
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: a5b282c7-24e7-46a6-ba22-4f74a31fa9bd,2232ec6c-b3e9-4e29-88e3-abf63675486c
Host: localhost:44370
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 122
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache

 {"Name": "Wednesday TestWithPostman",
    "Department": "Groan",
    "visitorcount": 0 }
```

Here is the API Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Consumes("application/json")] //https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4396
    public async Task<ActionResult<StaffNames>> PostStaffNames(StaffNames staffNames)
    {
        _context.StaffNames.Add(staffNames);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetStaffNames", new { id = staffNames.Id }, staffNames);
    }
```

My class is simple at this stage

```
public class StaffNames
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public int VisitorCount { get; set; }

}
```

And in my startup.cs I have the CORS set up

```
  //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2#ecors
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000/",
                        "http://www.contoso.com")
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod();
                });
        });
```

Here is my useCors

```
 app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52896068/reactasp-net-core-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-r
        app.UseCors(builder => builder
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials());
```

Thanks for your help, I have been pondering this for hours!

Comment: Hi David, without quotes I get an error    Line 40:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

Comment: I guess the cause is a problem with deserializing of posted JSON to `StaffNames` data type. It would be nice to see `StaffNames` class definition to be more certain...

Comment: @netchicken I am glad that you have resolved the problem with the solution which I have suggested in my answer.Did you see that?Could you accept the answer if you have no problems?

Answer (score 1):

If you have two projects, you need to set your mode as `cors`.And I met the same problem of CORS.Finally, I overcome it by removing the `/` in your original url like

```
services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
            builder =>
            {
                //Do not use `http://localhost:3000/`
                builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000",
                    "http://www.contoso.com")
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
    });

Configure method:
app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
```

React:

```
return fetch(baseUrl, {
        mode: "cors",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            Host: "localhost:44370",
            Allow: "GET, POST",
            Accept: "application/json, text/plain",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ Name: "tuesday", Department: "tuesday", visitorcount: 0 })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason using `no-cors` mode prevents setting `Content-Type` header value to `application/json` and it's set to `test/plain` by default which causes the issue. After some research I've found out that mode `cors` works fine for your case, so first of all consider learning more about all those modes and choose most suitable one for you.

And, secondly, you need to add `[FromBody]` attribute you action parameter in order to allow model binder parse `json` body on server side. On client side you need to serialize object to json before sending it since `fetch` doesn't do this for you. The minimal working code looks like this

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[Consumes("application/json")]
public IActionResult PostStaffNames([FromBody]StaffNames staffNames)
```

**React**

```
export function saveStaff(data) {
    return fetch(baseUrl, {
        mode: "cors",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    .then(handleResponse)
    .catch(handleError);
}
```

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for your ideas,  cors, just give me the error Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:44370/api/StaffNamesAPI' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:   I included my class, and my Cors setup in the Startup.cs file in my question as well.

Comment: @netchicken You are probably missing `UseCors` call in `Startup.Configure` method

Comment: Hi Alexander, I am using it :-) I have added to my original post with code from the startup.cs. I can call a GET from my website OK, its just the POST that doesn't work.

Comment: @netchicken Remove the trailing slash. It should be `http://localhost:3000` instead of `http://localhost:3000/`

Comment: Gaaarrr!!!! I hate training slashes :-)  Thanks so much for saving me from such an annoying error :-)

Comment: @netchicken No problem:) Please, consider accepting the answer if it was helpful