# has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, angular7

I have created one app using angular and springboot for basic authentication with spring security but i am getting 401 error ..i am novice in springboot

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfigurationBasicAuth extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{ 

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            //.formLogin().and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

> "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/hello-world/path-variable/MSD' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status."

Comment: Which plugin should i add??

Comment: You shouldn't add any chrome plugin. EIther your backend API is indeed supposed, once in production, to be called from other domains/ports, and you should add CORS support on your backend API, or it shouldn't, and your development environment should thus mimic the production environment by serving the backend and the frontend from the same host/port. You typically do that by using the Angular CLI server as a proxy to your backend API. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md

Comment: @Sachi.Dila don't suggest solutions that compromise someones web security without warning them. When you install a cors plugin, you allow any site to access any other site including allowing access to gmail.com from attacker.example.com. There have been attacks like this in the past for the careless developers who don't understand why a certain protection is in place

Comment: AFAIR when you want to allow authenticated access from different origins and these requests not being stopped by your browser, your backend must explicitely "allow" these origins telling the browser via the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header listing the allowed origins.

Comment: @MONI SHANKAR please try using my code I think it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue with angulat7 and spring boot I resolved by adding the following configuration

```
 @Configuration
    public class SpringDataRestConfiguration extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {

        config.getCorsRegistry().addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*").allowedHeaders("*").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PATCH", "PUT", "DELETE");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Does this work with authentication? Last time I checked, a "*" allowed origin is interpreted from browsers as "insecure" and thus does not allow authentication headers being sent.

Comment: I refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743396/cors-cannot-use-wildcard-in-access-control-allow-origin-when-credentials-flag-i

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following
At the top of the `controller`, you can add `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")` or customise if required

```
...
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
@RestController
public class UserController {
    // Methods
}
...
```

Please try above solution and let me know if this doesnt work

**EDIT 1:**
You could also try to create a filter with `CORS` options:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Order(1)
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleCORSFilter.class);

    public SimpleCORSFilter() {
        log.info("SimpleCORSFilter init");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        // HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me");

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

Please try with the `filters` method and let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")

@RestController
public class HelloWordlController {
 
 @GetMapping(path = "/hello-world")
 public String helloWorld() ...... That part i already added and i tried with ur code as well but it is not working bro

Comment: @MONISHANKAR have you added the allowance of credentials? Otherwise your browser won't send any.

Comment: @MONISHANKAR, added `filters` based solution. Please check once

Comment: @SagarCh thanks for ur code but i think ur code is related servlet and m using angular7 with springboot security..M not sure whether it will work or not..