# CORS origin is not working in Spring boot with Javax servlet Webfilter

Tags: java, spring-boot

I created a Rest API with java and spring boot.

Using `javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter` to check the authentication. It was working fine but facing

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy
```

issue So I use `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")` in my `@RestController class`

when I tried to access my rest api from my frontend application it shows `CROS policy` error in browser console and shows `401` error in server console.

When I remove `@WebFilter` annotation CROS origin is working fine.

How can I fix this issue.

**My Code**

**Spring boot version**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

**Controller.java**

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RequestMapping(value = "api")
public class Controller  {

}
```

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ServletComponentScan
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

**LoginHandleFilter.java**

@WebFilter(description = "Login and encoding filter", urlPatterns = {"/api/*"})
public class LoginHandleFilter implements Filter {

```
@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    String token = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    if(isAuthenticate(token)){
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }else{
        response.sendError(401);
    }
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}

private boolean isAuthenticate(String token){
    return token.equals("Mytoken");
}
```

}

**javascript**

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest():
http.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/api/", true);
http.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "TOKEN");
http.onreadystatechange = function(){

}
http.send();
```

Did I miss anything here?

Comment: I believe this has already been answered. You may check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56946280/has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass

Comment: Does this answer your question? [origin has been blocked by CORS policy Spring boot and React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59775325/origin-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-spring-boot-and-react)

Comment: @kulsin Thank you but still didn't work.

Comment: Check my config in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63292799/13039704

Answer (score 0):

Add this Configuration class. If you already have a WebMvcConfigurer, simply add the `addCorsMappings` method. The cors configuration provided through `CrossOrigin` annotation should then be read and the necessary header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` will get added into Response Header.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```