# How to fix ''http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, electron

I am currently working on a react app but when I run yarn start. I keep getting this issue Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://google.com/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

'web-preferences': {
        'web-security': false
    }

but the Moesif Orign & CORS Changer extension on chrome helped me bypass it but I am trying to fix it without an extension.

```
    const electron = require("electron");
    const app = electron.app;
    const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
    const path = require("path");
    const isDev = require("electron-is-dev");
    let mainWindow;
    let createWindow=()=> {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 900, height: 680 });
    mainWindow.loadURL(
    isDev
    ? "http://localhost:3000"
    : `file://${path.join(__dirname, "../build/index.html")}`
    );
    mainWindow.on("closed", () => (mainWindow = null));
    }
    app.on("ready", createWindow);
    app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
    if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
    }
    });
    app.on("activate", () => {
    if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
    }
    });
```

I am expecting to bypass this issue with out the Moesif Orign & CORS Changer extension on chrome.

Comment: hi @AdamOrlov I added the proxy in package.json  `  "devDependencies": {
    "proxy": "http://localhost:3000"`                                                                          but I am still having the same issue. 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS: Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743396/cors-cannot-use-wildcard-in-access-control-allow-origin-when-credentials-flag-i)

Comment: Not really, I am still having a hard time getting it to work but thanks for trying.

Comment: You cannot access google.com from your domain, because Google won't allow it. Google would need to return the CORS header, not you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem using expressjs and it's basically the same, here's the code I've used to deal wit CORS

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

// Defining CORS
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "X-Requested-With,content-type"
    );
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
      "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
    );
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    next();
});
```

hope this helps

Comment: HI where do we place this set of codes?

Comment: on your starting point, most people call it app.js or server.js (ts), doesn't matter what you call it but that code should be before the point where you start your server. check the code on this link https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html you may just take the code that I posted (from the comment till the end) and place it in line 4 of the example in that link

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm i --save cors` on the server, then

```
app.options("*", cors());
app.use(cors());
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).