# CORS support in spring boot and security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

I have configured `spring security` to enable `cors`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private CustomLogoutHandler logoutHandler;

    @Autowired
    private HttpLogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception
    {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()

                .authorizeRequests()

                .antMatchers("/rest/noauth/**").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/rest/login").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/rest/logout").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/ws/**").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/rest/razorpay/hook").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/rest/user/cc").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs/**", "/configuration/ui/**", "/swagger-resources/**",
                        "/configuration/security/**", "/swagger-ui.html/**", "/webjars/**")
                .permitAll()

                .anyRequest().authenticated()

                .and()

                .logout().addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler).logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
                .logoutUrl("/rest/logout")

                .and()

                .addFilterBefore(
                        new JWTAuthenticationFilter("/rest/login", tokenService(), refreshTokenService,
                                authTokenModelRepository, userService, userActivitiesRepository,
                                handlerExceptionResolver, bCryptPasswordEncoder, redisTemplate),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)

                .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), authTokenModelRepository,
                        userSubscriptionRepository, handlerExceptionResolver, redisTemplate),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    }

    @Override
    public void configure( AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth ) throws Exception
    {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }
  }
```

and I have a rest controller,

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping( RestEndPoints.NO_AUTH_CONTROLLER )
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://0.0.0.0:3000")
public class OtpController extends AbstractController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthService authService;

    @ApiOperation( value = "Generate OTP to login using registered email address", response = UIResponse.class, notes = "Please do validate and send only the organisation email address" )
    @ApiResponses( value = { @ApiResponse( code = 200, message = "Otp generated for <email_address>" ),
            @ApiResponse( code = 400, message = "Email address not registered as CC", response = UIErrorMessage.class ),
            @ApiResponse( code = 500, message = "Something went wrong", response = UIErrorMessage.class ) } )
    @PostMapping( "/otp/{email_address:.+}" )
    public ResponseEntity generateOtpToLogin( @PathVariable( "email_address" ) String emailAddress )
    {
        try
        {
            return buildResponse(authService.generateOtpForTheEmailAddress(emailAddress));
        }
        catch( DataException e )
        {
            return buildError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

But, when an API request is made from a frontend application to the `POST` method, the browser is making an `OPTIONS` call and that response headers as `Access-Control-Allowed-Origin:*` even though I am setting it to `0.0.0.0:3000` and the browser is getting the error,

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://192.168.1.3:8090/rest/noauth/otp/sandesha@test.com' from
>   origin 'http://0.0.0.0:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The
>   value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must
>   not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is
>   'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the
>   XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: I think it is linked with how you are making the request from front-end while configuring the wildcard "*" 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in backend. The combination of backend and frontend configurations is not correct. Please have a look at this link for example. [https://stackoverflow.com/q/19743396/10159797](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19743396/10159797)

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue earlier, I suppose it expect some other parameter also.

So that i place following code and it's working file for me.

```
package com.ecommerce.auth_service.service.jwt;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

  private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleCORSFilter.class);

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    String check = "xsrf-token,X-Total-Results,Authorization";

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me, Authorization");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers",check);

    if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
      log.debug("Request get method call status SC_OK.");
      response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    } else {
      log.debug("Request get method not work chain start.");
      chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have given answer to the same question in this **Stackoverflow** Question

[CORS errors using Spring Boot, Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76363383/7660727)