# CORS errors using Spring Boot, Spring Security and React

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

Good morning.

I have been fighting with this issue for the past two days so I decided to post a question about it.

Basically I have a Spring Boot project which executes basic CRUD operations through a React JS front-end.
Everything seemed to work fine until I added Spring Security to the project. Since then whenever I make a request (using axios) from the front-end I get the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/calciatore/list' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Before implementing Spring Security everything worked perfectly just using `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")` in my back-end controllers, but now I always get that error even if the URL is configured not to be protected through login by Spring Security.

In the meanwhile, I have no problems making any request (POST for login or GET for data fetching) from Postman.

I tried looking for a solution all around the internet but still didn't find one.

If you need me to show a portion of code just ask.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the global CORS config as shown in below code to allow CORS for all endpoints.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Component
public class CorsConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {

        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry
                        .addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedMethods(CorsConfiguration.ALL)
                        .allowedHeaders(CorsConfiguration.ALL)
                        .allowedOriginPatterns(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Since spring boot 2.4 you are supposed to use `allowedOriginPatterns` instead of `allowedOrigins`. Also you cannot use wildcard '*' along with `credentials : true`

Comment: If you're working with Spring-Security, you additionally need to mention `HttpSecurity#cors()` method in the security config. See [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors#cors-with-spring-security)

Answer (score 3):

In **older version** of Spring boot we **extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** in our **SecurityConfiguration** class but In **recent versions of Spring boot** , **Spring deprecates this approach and encourages a component-based security configuration**.

so if you using **component-based security configuration**. then
Inside **SecurityConfiguration** class, **after providing filters** to http inside **SecurityFilterChain** method, use **http.cors();** before building **http.build();**.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf()
        ----
        -----
    ;
    http.cors();    //  <- this is what you need to provide

    return http.build();
  }
}
```

and then in **restControllers** provide **@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")**  use your frontend url  instead of **3000**,

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/customer")
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")  // <- use your url of frontend
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/userName")
    public ResponseEntity<String> userName(HttpServletRequest request){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.getUserName(request));
    }
}
```

happy coding ☺️

Comment: http.cors() is the deprecated

Comment: Thanks alot!
As the comment above me mentions "http.cors()" indeed is "deprecated" BUT there is another http.cors(CorsConfigurationSource crs) which is the newer one, that perfectly solved it for myself

Answer (score 1):

For the latest Spring versions, that is,the component-based Spring security approach as mentioned [here](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter) in their docs, you'll need to enable cors and then configure a CorsConfigurationSource bean. Let's do it:

First, create the **`SecurityFilterChain`** bean configuration:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults()) //enables cors
                //The rest of your configurations 
         .build();
    }
```

The create a **`CorsConfigurationSource`** bean with the necessary configurations:

```
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:3000")); //allows React to access the API from origin on port 3000. Change accordingly
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

Now the application should work great.

Answer (score 0):

First create a Spring boot App with the following configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/api/**"))
                        .hasRole("ADMIN"))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .anyRequest()
                        .permitAll())
                .formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin
                        .loginPage("/authenticate")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/api/v1/hello", true))
                .anonymous(anonymous -> anonymous.disable())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user1 = User.builder()
                .username("user1")
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode("pass"))
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        UserDetails user2 = User.builder()
                .username("admin")
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode("pass"))
                .roles("ADMIN")
                .build();
        
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user1, user2);
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
      corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:5173"));
      corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Content-Type",
              "Accept", "Authorization", "X-Requested-With",
              "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers","Access-Control-Allow-Headers"));
      corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"));
      corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
              "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
      UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
      source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);

      return source;
    }
}
```

Then create an api

```java
@GetMapping(path = "authenticate")
//  @PostMapping(path = "authenticate")
    public ResponseEntity<String> authenticateUser(){
        try {
            Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            
            if (authentication != null && authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
                String username = authentication.getName();
                System.err.println("AUTHENTICATE: " + username);
                return ResponseEntity
                        .status(HttpStatus.OK)
                        .body("User: [" + username + "] Authenticated!");
            } else {
                return ResponseEntity
                        .status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
                        .body("User is not authenticated");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity
                    .status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
                    .body("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Then in your react app include

```js
import { Box, 
  AppBar, 
  Toolbar, 
  IconButton, 
  Typography, 
  Button, 
  TextField } from "@mui/material";
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const handleLogin = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      const formData = new URLSearchParams();
      formData.append('username', username);
      formData.append('password', password);
  
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:9001/spring-security-3/authenticate', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: formData,
        credentials: 'include',
      });
  
      if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.text();
        console.log('Login successful Data: ', data);
        alert(data);
      } else {
        console.error('Login failed');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Login failed', error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
    <AppBar position="static">
      <Toolbar>
        <IconButton
          size="large"
          edge="start"
          color="inherit"
          aria-label="menu"
          sx={{ mr: 2 }}
        >
          <MenuIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <Typography variant="h6" component="div" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
          client-login-3
        </Typography>
        <Button color="inherit">Signup</Button>
        <Button color="inherit" onClick={handleLogin}>Login</Button>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
    <div>
        <h2>Authenticate</h2>
        <form>
          <div>
            <TextField
              label="Username"
              variant="outlined"
              value={username}
              onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <TextField
              label="Password"
              type="password"
              variant="outlined"
              value={password}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleLogin}>Login</Button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
  </Box>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Please do include this credentials: 'include', in your fetch method as this ensures that cookies are sent in the cross-origin request, allowing the server to authenticate the user's session.