# Why are Cookies Not Sent on Requests in MERN Application using Axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js, express-session

I'm trying to implement login using `passport.js` with `express-session` following the example [here](https://github.com/dikuw/mern-passport) but I'm having trouble persisting logins. I notice the session cookie is not being sent on any route unless the route includes `passport.authenticate('local')`, which adds the cookie I guess. This means the `/getUser` route always returns no user, and a new session is added to the MongoDB store every time I login.

My routes are as follows:

```
router.get('/getUser', userController.getCurrentUser);
router.post('/register', userController.register, passport.authenticate('local'), authController.login);
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), authController.login);
router.post('/logout', authController.logout);
```

Controlling functions are:

```
exports.getCurrentUser = (req, res) => {
  if (req.user) {
    return res.send(req.user);
  } else {
    res.json({ error: 'No user found' });
  };
};

exports.register = async (req, res, next) => {
  const user = new User({ 
    email: req.body.email, 
    name: req.body.name,
  });
  const register = promisify(User.register, User);
  await register(user, req.body.password);
  next();
};

exports.login = (req, res) => {
  req.login(req.user, function(err) {
    if (err) { res.json({ error: err }); }
    return res.send(req.user);
  });
};

exports.logout = (req, res) => {
  if (req.user) {
    req.logout();
    res.send({ msg: 'logged out' });
  } else {
    res.send({ msg: 'no user to log out' })
  };
};
```

User model is:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const validator = require('validator');
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
    trim: true,
    validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Please enter a valid email'],
    required: 'Please enter an email address'
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Please enter a name',
    trim: true
  },
  resetPasswordToken: String,
  resetPasswordExpires: Date,
  isAdmin: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
}, { timestamps: true });

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, { usernameField: 'email' });

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Axios module in the FE:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/api',
});

export const getUser = () => api.get('/getUser');
export const register = payload => api.post('/register', payload);
export const login = payload => api.post('/login', payload);
export const logout = payload => api.post('/logout', payload);

const apis = {
  getUser,
  register,
  login,
  logout,
};

export default apis;
```

Passport config is:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('User');
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, { _id: user._id });
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findOne({ _id: id },   'username', (err, user) => {
        done(null, user)
    });
});

const strategy = new LocalStrategy(
    {   usernameField: 'email'  },
    function(email, password, done) {
        User.findOne({ email: email }, (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }
);

passport.use(strategy);

module.exports = passport;
```

And finally server config is:

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const promisify = require('es6-promisify');
//  import all models
require('./models/User');

const passport = require('./handlers/passport');

const db = require('./database');
const router = require('./routes');

const app = express();

//  enable CORS for all origins to allow development with local server
app.use(cors({credentials: true}));

// use bodyParser to allow req.params and req.query
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  key: process.env.KEY,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
}));

// passport.js to handle logins
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// pass variables on all requests
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  res.locals.session = req.session;
  next();
});

// promisify some callback based APIs
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.login = promisify(req.login, req);
  next();
});

app.use('/api', router);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('This is the Hely Cosmetics website backend/API');
})

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8000);
const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log(`Express running on port ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

I thought it might be cors but I tried `app.use(cors({credentials: true}));` with the same result, and verified the same issues with both the frontend and backend deployed as Heroku apps.

Full source code is available [here](https://github.com/dikuw/Hely).

What am I missing?

Comment: Any console error when the request is sent?

Comment: No, the requests go through fine and return 200, but I can see there's no cookie on them (except register and login, which I assume passport puts the cookie on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a glance at the full source code, it doesn't look like you've set `withCredentials: true` in the Axios requests you're making to your backend. Passport, at a high level, works like this:

1. Your `/login` and `/register` routes send a cookie back in their response. This is stored by your browser for future requests to identify the session (which, by your comment, seem to be working correctly).
2. When you want to make an authenticated request to your backend, Axios has to explicitly send the cookie back in the request if it's cross-origin — that's where `withCredentials` comes in. Without it, Axios isn't sending the cookie with the request to identify the session.

By setting `withCredentials: true`, Axios should send the cookie back in the requests and Passport & express-session will use it to identify the user.

Comment: If I add ` withCredentials: true` I get CORS policy erros, on localhost and the heroku app, which doesnot make sense to me. `Access to XMLHttpRequest at '...' from origin '...' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.`

Comment: You can't use the default CORS settings when sending cookies as it's insecure — see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45890875/3813411) how to change for `localhost` (and similarly you would do that for Heroku if you needed CORS enabled).

Comment: Also, I don't see `withCredentials: true` explicitly set in the example app (https://github.com/dikuw/mern-passport) and it works as expected.

Comment: okay with `app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:3000'}));` there is no CORS error and login does not create an additional session! So one issue is resolved. But login is still not persisted on reload. Maybe a new question?

Comment: Glad to hear we got one issue resolved. Probably best to create a new question and link here since there you can provide more info as to what behavior you're seeing.

Comment: And to answer your question as to why it's working as expected in the example app — the key difference is it's proxied in the example app. In other words, all requests are coming from `localhost:8080` — credentials get sent automatically if it's on the same domain. However in your app, you have your client and server running on different ports, so credentials aren't automatically sent as this is a cross-origin request, and for [very good reason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) security-wise.