# mitmproxy - Nested Requests

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, mitmproxy

I am using mitmproxy* to redirect web traffic in my automation suite. I usually have to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers in the response to hit all of the endpoints correctly.

I have a request I would like to make, but it references another endpoint and I am now receiving a CORS error because I cannot set the headers in that nested response. For some reason that request has my website's origin, but doesn't go through the proxy.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at $ENDPOINT from origin $MY_WEBSITE has been
> blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
> header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's
> credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests
> initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials
> attribute.

Is it possible to get around this problem of a nested response, or is this a limitation of mitmproxy?

*I should note I'm using mitmdump, mitmproxy's command line version

Answer (score 0):

The JS error you posted does not indicate a mitmproxy problem to me. As the error states, it seems like you are setting access control headers incorrectly. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19744754/934719 has a succinct explanation.