# 403 error with PUT request using angular and spring boot service with JWT

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, spring-security, xmlhttprequest

```
package com.example.invoiceapp.security;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.HttpStatusEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;


@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = { "/v2/api-docs", "/swagger-resources", "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/configuration/ui", "/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**" };

    public SecurityConfiguration(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors().configurationSource(configurationSource()).and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/authenticate/signup").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)).and()
                .addFilter(new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager())).sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().formLogin().usernameParameter("email");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder() );
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource configurationSource() {
        
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
//      configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
//      configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
//      configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
        
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

I am trying to do a PUT request from the front end angular application but the pre flight request of OPTIONS is failing and giving the error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://invoice-backend-heroku.herokuapp.com/api/invoices/5fe8353905dfdc66e95e7269' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Even though I have allowed all origins and methods. I am not sure on how else to configure my corsconfiguration to make it work. My POST request for the same spring boot service is working just fine as well as GET request.

Answer (score 1):

```
      @Bean
      CorsConfigurationSource configurationSource() {
        
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration.applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }
```

you  should use the reference object configuration in  source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration.applyPermitDefaultValues()); instead of creating new Object new CorsConfiguration()

Comment: Thanks for noticing that, i changed it and it didn't work until i explicitly added my domain in the configuration

`configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));`

reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743396/cors-cannot-use-wildcard-in-access-control-allow-origin-when-credentials-flag-i