# The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.-

Tags: node.js, angular, express, cors, session-cookies

I am trying to connect my angular app with nodejs with graphql api and I'm using cookies/sessions for auth.

The api works perfectly with GraphQL PLayground.
This is my angular connection to connect with graphql api.

```
const uri = "http://localhost:4000/graphql/"; // <-- add the URL of the GraphQL server here

export function createApollo(httpLink: HttpLink): ApolloClientOptions<any> {
  return {
    link: httpLink.create({ uri, withCredentials: true }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  };
}
```

The connection is made if I set `withCredentials:false` but I can't use cookies for auth anymore.

---

This is my code on the cors middleware.

```
    const corsOptions = {
      credentials: true,
      origin: "http://localhost:4200",
    };
    app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

---

I've tried the following code snippets in an effort to make this work but none worked.

```
  app.use(function (req, res, next) {
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
      res.header(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept",
      );
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
      next();
    });
```

```
    const corsOptions = {
      credentials: true,
      origin: true,
    };
    app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

This is the exact error that is being displayed.
[image: This is the exact error]

---

I've tried all solutions from the question link below.
Related Questions:

- [CORS: Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743396/cors-cannot-use-wildcard-in-access-control-allow-origin-when-credentials-flag-i)
- [Why does my JavaScript code receive a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error, while Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i)

... and similar posts but none have solved this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app, cors: false });` while creating server or else it will seem as there are two cors blockers in the app and either one of them will throw any clients trying to connect,

Answer (score 0):

Either add cors settings to the top part using `app.use(cors(....))` or add it while adding apolloServer as middleware.

Comment: You're right, the code I'd written two cors in it which were simultaneously blocking my ping.