# Cors Origin Error. Works on local but not when I deploy on heroku

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, cors

I am using the code below to run my nodejs backend server. Angular front end has to communicate with the server. While I am using it on localhost everything works fine. However when I deploy my code on heroku I keep getting
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'heroku app link' from origin 'https:[https://iprocopiou.com/.com'](https://iprocopiou.com/.com%27) has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Does anyone know what I am missing here?

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const corsOptions = {
origin: "*",
methods: ["GET","HEAD","PUT","PATCH","POST","DELETE"],
credentials: true,
preflightContinue:false
}

require("./startup/logging")();
require("./startup/routes")(app);
require("./startup/db")();
require("./startup/config")();
require("./startup/validation")();
require("./startup/prod")(app);

app.use(cors(corsOptions))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () =\> console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

I have tried almost every solution that I found...

Answer (score -1):

For security reasons you need to specify the exact URL or URLS origin (protocol + domain + port) when you want to allow and share credentials, you cannot use *.

```
 const corsOptions = {
    origin: "https://iprocopiou.com",  // or your exact URL you allow to make request
    methods: ["GET","HEAD","PUT","PATCH","POST","DELETE"],
    credentials: true,
    preflightContinue:false
 }

//...
app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```

you can also see more detail in this threat [CORS: Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743396/cors-cannot-use-wildcard-in-access-control-allow-origin-when-credentials-flag-i)