# Angular Http Interceptor - Modifying headers causes CORS

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I have defined an http interceptor. Inside the interceptor I have the following code:

```js
let newReq = req.clone({
  withCredentials: true,
  responseType: 'json'
});
```

Now I need to modify all requests and add an extra header `Demo` with the value of foo

I tried the following

```js
let newReq = req.clone({
  withCredentials: true,
  responseType: 'json',
  setHeaders: {'Demo' : 'foo'}
});
```

However I notice in the network tab that this removes almost all headers including `Host` & `Origin` from my request and it leads to CORS issues with the API that I am communicating with

Is there any way to fix this issue ? (I want to have all previous headers in my cloned request and just add a new one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be working fine and and it does send the previous and new headers successfully. The culprit is the option `withCredentials: true` which causes the following error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has
> been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't
> pass access control check: **The value of the
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the
> wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'**. The
> credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is
> controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

As the error suggests, the server is probably sending header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in pre-flight check (response of OPTIONS request). Your request will only work if server sends the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200 (or whatever your origin is)`.

The reason why you cannot `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in combination with `withCredentials: true` is explained here: [CORS: Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743396/cors-cannot-use-wildcard-in-access-control-allow-origin-when-credentials-flag-i)

I created a backend to reproduce this issue. Doing following steps will solve your problem:

- Add `http://localhost:4200` (or your origin) to the allow CORS origin list (you cannot set it as `*`).
- Allow custom headers to be passed to your backend by setting `access-control-allow-headers` to `*`.
- Set `allow_credentials` in your CORS settings to `true`.

If you are using Python (Fast API), you can do above settings like this (tested and works):

```py
app = FastAPI()

origins = [
    "http://localhost:4200"
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

If you are using .NET Core, you can do above settings like this (not tested):

```cs
var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                          policy =>
                          {
                              policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                                                  .AllowAnyHeader()
                                                  .AllowAnyMethod()
                                                  .AllowCredentials();
                          });
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Also do similar settings on IIS (if you are using IIS).

- `allowCredentials="true"`
- `allowAllRequestedHeaders="true"`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <cors enabled="true" failUnlistedOrigins="true">
            <add origin="http://localhost:4200"
                 allowCredentials="true"
                 maxAge="120"> 
                <allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true">
                    <add header="Demo" />
                </allowHeaders>
                <allowMethods>
                     <add method="DELETE" />
                     <add method="GET" />
                     <add method="POST" />
                     <add method="PUT" />
                     <add method="OPTIONS" />
                </allowMethods>
            </add>
        </cors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I am looking at the backend cors (dotnetcore) and I see that they have added the http://localhost:4200 origin. That is what bothers me

Comment: Does backend also allow your demo header?  `access-control-allow-headers: demo`

Comment: Yes I see it has allow any header

Comment: I will test it later with a proper backend, right now I was testing it with https://webhook.site/ and unfortunately it doesn't allow headers to be set and sent back to the client.

Comment: @ManosKounelakis your backend has an issue, I was able to reproduce and solve the issue. Check updated answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My project has 2 configuration. 1 is IIS server and the other is dev . I found out that it happends only when I run the IIS configuration. So it must have to do something with this

Comment: No worries, IIS also has similar settings. Added some of the IIS settings in answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're adding a new header and that's causing the problem, my guess is that this is because the server is not including `Demo` in the Access-Control-Allow-Headers part of the OPTIONS response:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers

I think you probably need to fix this on the backend.

Comment: Hi . My issue is that all the previous headers (Host , Origin , etc are removed from my cloned request) not from the response. Sorry I have update my answer