# .Net core SignalR cors issue

Tags: c#, vue.js, signalr, .net-core-3.1

I try use SignalR with `.net core 3.1`, Its the first time i need to use it. I have no expirience with SignalR.
It seems like the same code working on `.NET 5`, Unless im missing something

I tried understand why i get the error with no success.
In my API endpoitns i dont have CORS errors
I get the error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://XXX:5421/managerhub/negotiate' from origin 'http://XXX:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

My hub class:

```
[EnableCors("AnotherPolicy")]
    public class TestHub : Hub
    {
        IHubContext<TestHub> _hubContext = null;
        private static bool _firstTime = true;
        
        public TestHub(IHubContext<TestHub> hubContext)
        {
            if (_firstTime)
            {
                _firstTime = false;
            }
            _hubContext = hubContext;


            Task.Run(() => {
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
                Update(null,1);

            });
        }

        [EnableCors("AnotherPolicy")]
        public void Update(object sender, ushort participantId)
        {
            _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("test", participantId);
        }

    }
```

My Services:

```
...
var corsBuilder = new CorsPolicyBuilder();
corsBuilder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();

            
services.AddCors(opt => {
   opt.AddPolicy("AnotherPolicy", corsBuilder.Build());
});
```

Configure:

```
...
            app.UseCors("AnotherPolicy");

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();

                endpoints.MapHub<TestHub>("/managerhub", options =>
                 {
                 }).RequireCors("AnotherPolicy");
            });
```

And my client code:

```
import { HubConnectionBuilder, LogLevel } from "@aspnet/signalr";

const Url =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
    ? "http://localhost:5421"
    : location.origin;

const SignalR = (function () {
  let status;
  let _connected = false;
  let _managerHub = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(Url + `/managerhub`)
    .configureLogging(LogLevel.Information)
    .build();

  let _retryTimerId;
  let _registeredEvents = [];

  function UpdateStatus(moreInfo = "") {
    console.log(
      "%c SignalR ",
      "background: #148F77; color: white;",
      `${status}${moreInfo ? "; " + moreInfo : ""}`
    );
  }

  function StartConnection() {
    if (_connected) return;
    _managerHub
      .start()
      .then(() => {
        _retryTimerId = undefined;
        _connected = true;
        status = "Connected";
        UpdateStatus(`id: ${_managerHub.id}`);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        // console.error(e);
        _connected = false;

        status = "Disconnected";
        UpdateStatus();
       
      });
    
  }

  StartConnection();
```

Comment: `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'` - notice that you specified the .net to allow any origin by using `corsBuilder.AllowAnyOrigin()`, see [relevant QA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19744754).