# Preflight (OPTIONS) requests with authentication header

Tags: cors, asp.net-web-api

I have to make CORS with content type JSON.  We have used `[ApiAuthorization]` filter in our get method as mentioned below.

```
  [AcceptVerbs("Get", "Options")]
  [ApiAuthorization]
        public response GetDetails()
        {
```

In case of preflight(option) request  we are getting 401 Unauthorized error. What is a correct way to pass authentication header in this scenarios with CORS?

Comment: Your server should not require authentication for preflight requests, as there is no way to add custom headers to these requests.

Comment: I've run into same issue, here is my [solution][1] with ServiceStack


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10820339/48262