# Angular js wep api windows authentication in chrome extension

Tags: angularjs, security, google-chrome-extension, windows-authentication

I  use wep api + angular js for intranet application.I want to activite windows authentication.It is work for internet explorer well.But when I try it chrome browser only get methods working.I dont want to disable  Chrome launcher: --disable-web-security.Is there a work around?

[AngularJS not detecting Access-Control-Allow-Origin header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102690/angularjs-not-detecting-access-control-allow-origin-header)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome sending post/put request as options format.

Authorization headers with OPTIONS request, so on server side if you enable Windows integrated authentication, it does reject the OPTIONS request.So you have to open windows authentication and anonymous authentication both if you open only windows authentication you get this error.

If you use IE it sends request with post or put format but chrome send it to options method format for that reason you get error in chrome.

You can check for details in these topics

[401 response for CORS request in IIS with Windows Auth enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723088/401-response-for-cors-request-in-iis-with-windows-auth-enabled/23663174#comment40493218_23663174)

[Can't set a header using Cors and Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665003/cant-set-a-header-using-cors-and-ajax)