# BeginRequest Not Hit By Options Request

Tags: asp.net, http, iis-7.5

I need to set up CORS for my Asp.net Application.

I need to use WindowsAuthentification so i tried Interception the Option Requests just like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/32351283/969175

I used Curl to send a request like curl -X OPTIONS "http://localhost:3333/", but the BeginRequest method is never hit. Other Requests Like Get hit BegeinRequestMethod.

The Application is hosted on IIS7.5 and uses an integrated AppPool.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Please, look at this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624386/handling-cors-preflight-requests-to-asp-net-mvc-actions?noredirect=1&lq=1. Config from this answer helps me.